# Coreldraw export filter object model

Tags: coreldraw

Can anyone help me about `exportfilter` object model in coreldraw? I can't find any good information on this topic, except sample code that I do not understand how it comes to be? I new on vba coreldraw.

```
Dim exF as ExportFilter
From object browser ExportFilter has
Finish - method
HasDialog - properties
Reset - method
ShowDialog - method

My questions how many sample code that scattered on many forum about coreldraw vba can include for example,

With exF
    m_Compression = .Compression
    m_Smoothing = .Smoothing
    m_bOptimized = .Optimized
    m_Progressive = .Progressive
    m_Subformat = .Subformat
End With
I am sorry but i copy those above code from JPGExportOptions just to get the picture what the question i ask to this forum
How can i find and know that JPGExportFilter has
.Compression
.Smoothing
.Optimized
etc

 All this is JPGExportFilter object model, i just want to know why this properties or method does not reveal on object browser vba window and does not have any help associated with all those ExportFilter object model
```

How do I call myself a professional programmer if I was only able to copy programs that were made by someone else. I just want to know the details of ExportFilter class. Unfortunately, very few books that discuss coreldraw vba. This site http://www.oberonplace.com/vba/filter10vba.htm good but, I need more information than just a list, I need an explanation of each member of the class - properties and methods - and how to use it in real code.

Thanks

Comment: hai Gab thanks for your corrections on my question? Can you help me?

Comment: hai wruckie i am sorry coz i am new in this forum. I need more your patient to guide on this forum especially when i post a question. Please forgive me if i make to many mistake on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Corel Draw X7 you should be able to find documentation of the object model at `%PROGRAMFILES%\Corel\CorelDRAW Graphics Suite X7\Data`. Unfortunately this documentation is not available online for reference or hyperlinking.

In Corel Draw X7 you call ExportEx on the object you want to export and pass along export options in the form of a `StructExportOptions` object. You can read all about the options in the documentation mentioned above.

Sample from the documentation:

```
Sub Test() 
 Dim d As Document 
 Dim s As Shape 
 Dim opt As New StructExportOptions 
 Dim pal As New StructPaletteOptions 
 Dim Filter As ExportFilter 
 Set d = CreateDocument 
 Set s = d.ActiveLayer.CreateEllipse2(4, 5, 2) 
 s.Fill.ApplyFountainFill CreateRGBColor(255, 0, 0), CreateRGBColor(0, 0, 0) 
 opt.AntiAliasingType = cdrNormalAntiAliasing 
 opt.ImageType = cdrRGBColorImage 
 opt.ResolutionX = 72 
 opt.ResolutionY = 72 
 pal.PaletteType = cdrPaletteOptimized 
 pal.NumColors = 16  
 pal.DitherType = cdrDitherNone 
 Set Filter = d.ExportEx("C:\Temp\Doc.gif", cdrGIF, cdrCurrentPage, opt, pal) 
 If Filter.ShowDialog() Then 
  If Not Filter.Interlaced Then 
   MsgBox "Interlaced is not specified... Fixing this." 
   Filter.Interlaced = True 
  End If 
  Filter.Finish 
 Else 
  MsgBox "Export canceled" 
 End If 
End Sub
```